# Extract certificate from .sys file

Tags: command-line, driver, digital-certificate

Is it possible to extract the digital signature certificate from a sys driver file by command line?

Either using 3rd party tool or built in windows tools?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Using powershell it's quite easy:

```
$driverFile = 'C:\temp\myDriver.sys';
$outputFile = 'C:\temp\output.cer';
$exportType = [System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509ContentType]::Cert;

$cert = (Get-AuthenticodeSignature $driverFile).SignerCertificate;
[System.IO.File]::WriteAllBytes($outputFile, $cert.Export($exportType));
```